# jQuery check if one of first 7 checkboxes are checked then hide element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide/show an element depending on whether 1 or more check-boxes from a group have been checked, I need to use the change event to trigger it once any of the checkboxes have been changed.

Here is what I have:

```
// List of my checkboxes (first 7)
var group = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1 input:lt(7)');


group.change(function () {
    if (group.filter(':checked').length > 0) {
    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_4_What_is_the_rationale_for_such_prioritisation_divContainer").show();
    }
    else {
    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_4_What_is_the_rationale_for_such_prioritisation_divContainer").hide();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1" class="text" style="width:500px;">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td><div class="checker" id="uniform-ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_0"><span class="checked"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Common1$cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation$CheckBoxList1$0" checked="checked" value="A) General education (compulsory / upper secondary)" style="opacity: 0;"></span></div><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_0">A) General education (compulsory / upper secondary)</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><div class="checker" id="uniform-ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_1"><span class="checked"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Common1$cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation$CheckBoxList1$1" checked="checked" value="B) Initial VET" style="opacity: 0;"></span></div><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_1">B) Initial VET</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><div class="checker" id="uniform-ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_2"><span><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Common1$cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation$CheckBoxList1$2" value="C) Continuing VET" style="opacity: 0;"></span></div><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_2">C) Continuing VET</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><div class="checker" id="uniform-ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_3"><span><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_3" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Common1$cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation$CheckBoxList1$3" value="D) Adult education" style="opacity: 0;"></span></div><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_3">D) Adult education</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><div class="checker" id="uniform-ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_4"><span><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_4" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Common1$cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation$CheckBoxList1$4" value="E) Higher education" style="opacity: 0;"></span></div><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_4">E) Higher education</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><div class="checker" id="uniform-ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_5"><span><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_5" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Common1$cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation$CheckBoxList1$5" value="F) Labour market sectors – please specify sector / branch if applicable" style="opacity: 0;"></span></div><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_5">F) Labour market sectors – please specify sector / branch if applicable</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><div class="checker" id="uniform-ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_6"><span><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_6" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Common1$cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation$CheckBoxList1$6" value="G) Third sector – please specify, e.g. youth sector, voluntary sector etc. if applicable" style="opacity: 0;"></span></div><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_6">G) Third sector – please specify, e.g. youth sector, voluntary sector etc. if applicable</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><div class="checker" id="uniform-ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_7"><span><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_7" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Common1$cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation$CheckBoxList1$7" value="H) No priority (all sectors are similarly prioritised)" style="opacity: 0;"></span></div><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_7">H) No priority (all sectors are similarly prioritised)</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><div class="checker" id="uniform-ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_8"><span><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_8" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Common1$cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation$CheckBoxList1$8" value="I) No priority (there is little activity in all sectors)" style="opacity: 0;"></span></div><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_8">I) No priority (there is little activity in all sectors)</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><div class="checker" id="uniform-ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_9"><span><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_9" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Common1$cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation$CheckBoxList1$9" value="J) Information not available" style="opacity: 0;"></span></div><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_9">J) Information not available</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><div class="checker" id="uniform-ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_10"><span><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_10" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Common1$cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation$CheckBoxList1$10" value="K) Do not know" style="opacity: 0;"></span></div><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_3_Are_any_sectors_prioritised_in_your_country_in_the_area_of_validation_CheckBoxList1_10">K) Do not know</label></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

This doesn't seem to work, does nothing. Any ideas why?

Comment: try `input:checkbox:lt(7)`

Comment: then inside the change event handler it should be as simple as `$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Common1_cbl_1_4_What_is_the_rationale_for_such_prioritisation_divContainer").toggle(group.is(':checked'));`

Comment: can you show your HTML please?

Comment: @ArunPJohny That doesn't do anything :/

Comment: Your code works? https://jsfiddle.net/nby7t9qc/ - you are starting with 2 boxes checked, uncheck them both and you will see that the test text at the bottom dissapears, then check any of the first 7 and it will appear again

Comment: The code works indeed, the OP had not checked the **spelling** of his *selector* - this is also the reason we needed to see the HTML :)

Comment: Ah, it does work indeed, I think it confused me when I was testing whether it worked or not, thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 1):

In `onchange` event of checkbox you can do something like this

```
if ($(".checker input:checkbox:checked").length > 0)
{
    // any one is checked
}
else
{
   // none is checked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT

You have indeed just spelled your selector wrong, simple mistake :)
If something is not right it's not instantly an error but you have to be able to see something that can't be seen sometimes since this doesn't give you any errors yet it doesn't work either.

The first things that you can skid through are checking if the element is physically in the document and if you're using the right attribute to target it, then there's the spelling errors that you can also check.

It's not really normal to have a selector this long, I assume they are dynamically created but if that is the case it's more like a ticking time bomb than you might think, as your JS will *stop working for no reason* again when you update the code that creates the selectors.

My advice would be to shorten your selectors or hard-code them so they never change (using a different attribute like `class` maybe?) - if your ID's **are** created dynamically you're going to run into issues with this sooner or later (unless you also dynamically generate the jQuery code that executes this, I guess)

---

#### ORIGINAL

Just created a quick snippet of how I would implement this using the `onchange` handler via jQuery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

The main reasons your script might not be working are

- Overly complex selectors that could be spelled wrong (one character is enough to mismatch)
- No `$(function() { ... })` used to check if the `$(document).ready(fn)` handler has been fired.

*Note: It's an example that includes CSS, you'd want to use your own styling ofcourse*

```js
$(function() { // equivelant of $(document).ready(fn)
  $('#toggle').css('display', 'none');
  var cb_group = $('.test-cb:lt(7)').on('change', function() {
    if (cb_group.filter(':checked').length)
      $('#toggle').show();
    else
      $('#toggle').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#toggle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1. <input type="checkbox" class="test-cb" name="checkbox" /><br />
2. <input type="checkbox" class="test-cb" name="checkbox" /><br />
3. <input type="checkbox" class="test-cb" name="checkbox" /><br />
4. <input type="checkbox" class="test-cb" name="checkbox" /><br />
5. <input type="checkbox" class="test-cb" name="checkbox" /><br />
6. <input type="checkbox" class="test-cb" name="checkbox" /><br />
7. <input type="checkbox" class="test-cb" name="checkbox" /><br />
8. <input type="checkbox" class="test-cb" name="checkbox" /><br />
9. <input type="checkbox" class="test-cb" name="checkbox" />

<div id="toggle">Test</div>
```